# App not showing for tablets in the play store

Tags: android, android-manifest, tablet

This is my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <!-- all xlare size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />

</compatible-screens>
```

Why is it not showing for tablets?
Thanks!

Comment: for all versions of tab or for particular android version?

Comment: Old nexus 7 for example with os version 4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is if your tablet doesn't support memory card means **external storage** and you add this permission in manifest then your app not viewed in play-store for tablet.

Answer (score 0):

put `android:largeScreens="true"`